# Need to know basic knowledge on redis

Tags: redis

I'm new to redis, have doubt on below commands

In redis-cli i have entered info keyspace, for this i got the following output

```
# Keyspace
db0:keys=2,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
```

What does the above lines represent. N how to get the value from key.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at https://redis.io/commands/INFO
To be specific the keyspace is, as mention in the official doc:

> Database related statistics
>
> The keyspace section provides statistics on the main dictionary of each database. The statistics are the number of keys, and the number of keys with an expiration.
>
> For each database, the following line is added:
>
> dbXXX: keys=XXX,expires=XXX

So in your case you have 2 keys present in redis